# Matlab optimization - Variable bounds have "donut hole"

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem using Matlab's genetic algorithm and fmincon functions where the variables' values do not have single upper and lower bounds. Instead, the variables should be allowed to take a value of x=0 or be lb<=x<=ub. This is a turbine allocation problem, where the turbine can either be turned off (x=0) or be within the lower and upper cavitation limits (lb and ub). Of course I can trick the problem by creating a constraint which will violate for values in between 0 and lb, but I'm finding that the problem is having a hard time converging like this. Is there an easier way to do this, which will trim down the search space?

Comment: Did you make any progress on that issue? I have a simiar problem. I have to optimize weights being either 0 or above a threshold and optimizing all possible combinations of weights being switched on/off just doesn't 'feel' right.

Comment: @ymihere, no luck so far. I feel like this is a common constraint scenario, so someone must have found a good way to handle it...

Answer (score 0):

If the number of variables is small enough (say, like 10 or 15 or less) then you can try every subset of variables that are set to be non-zero, and see which subset gives you the optimal value. If you can't make assumptions about the structure of your optimization problem (e.g. you have penalties for non-zero variables but your main objective function is "exotic"), this is essentially the best that you can do. If you are willing to settle for an approximate solution, you can add a so-called "L1" penalty to your objective function which is the sum of a constant times the absolute values of the variables. This will encourage some variables to be zero, and if your main objective function is convex then the resulting objective function will be convex because negative absolute value is convex. It's much easier to optimize convex functions (taking the minimum) because strictly convex functions always have a global minimum that you can reach using any number of optimization routines (including the ones that are implemented in matlab.)

Comment: The number of variables is much higher than that (several hundred). The objective and non-linear constraint functions are complicated...definitely not continuous or convex. I wasn't saying that any variables need to be zero...in fact, they could all be nonzero if that satisfies the other constraints. I think that's what you meant by "This will encourage some variables to be zero," but I had trouble following your logic so I may have misunderstood. Also, using a genetic algorithm has no guarantee of finding the global optimum, so the solution can be thought of as "approximate" regardless.